# 5A supply for 5A rated header

Tags: power-supply, pcb, header

I have a 24v, 5A power supply into a PCB. Is it okay if the header that it goes into is rated for 5A? (the same current it is taking) or do i need to upgrade and find a header with a higher rating?

Comment: How much current do you expect the PCB to draw?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of passing a reliability audit, it is better to have connectors overrated for the loads they carry.  A common value is 2:1.  That is, use a 10 A connector for a 5 A circuit.  Of course there are exceptions, and cost can be a significant factor in the decision.  One possible way around this is to use multiple pins in parallel.

Another way to state this is in terms of a derating factor, which would be 50% in this example.  This is very common in specifying electronic components, and sometimes enforced with written in-house rules.  For example, use a 200 V transistor in a 100 V circuit, a 3 A diode in a 1.5 A circuit, a 2 W resistor in a 1 W application, etc.

Something to consider is the number of pins in a connector.  You might find buried in the fine print that a 5 A rating for a connector pin applies to an individual pin, not multiple pins.  That is, a pin is rated for 5 A only if none of the pins around it are conducting anything (getting warm).  The rating assumes the connector body and surrounding pins can act as a heatsink; poor, but better than nothing.

Also, saying a pin is rated for 5 A does not mean it will run forever at that load.  The stated MTBF might be only a few thousand hours.  This is a common problem with electrolytic capacitors.  Many caps rated for 105C operation also are rated for only 2000-3000 hours.  Running 24/7, that's only 4 months.

Ya got-Got-GOT to read the datasheet.